# Calculate values in two different ways - A or B?

Tags: mysql

My question is about code and database design. How should I design my code to calculate simple variables (stored in sqlite db) like the balance of a wallet?

Example:
We have **tables** for **customers**, **wallets**, **transactions**. We have methods to fill these tables. When receiving money from a customer, we add the amount to the **balance** of a wallet and submit a **transaction** (date, amount, ...) into the **transactions** table.

I have 2 approaches to design my code and database - which one is more appropriate and bugfree?

***A)***
When doing a transaction I **add / subtract** the amount to my the **balance** of a wallet and submit a **transaction** into a table **transaction** with information like **wallet_id**, **amount**, **date**...

***B)***
I just submit the **transaction** to the **transactions** table and recalculate the **balance** of a specific wallet by checking for columns with the matching **wallet_id** and add up the wallet_balance from there.

Which is the right way? For me ***A)*** looks more prone to bugs and safe code requires more effort. I would go with ***B)*** which would be much easier then I would add more features like deleting transactions (+ recalculating balances) and so on.

What is your advice?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for your participation. Your question contains **bold** and non-bold names for tables and (possibly) columns. It would help if you could format your question and provide full DDL statements for the hypothetical tables. Even a quick listing of the tables with possible columns would help interpret your question (including reference ID columns...).

Answer (score 3):

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO transactions ... (info about the transfer of funds)...;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance - $amt WHERE acct_id = $me;
UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance + $amt WHERE acct_id = $you;
COMMIT;
```

That guarantees that either *all* 3 actions happened, or *none of them*, even in the case of a power failure.

Yes, this violates the don't-store-redundant-data rule, but it is standard practice, and much more efficient.

Another accounting note:  Do not ever `DELETE` or `UPDATE` `transactions`, only `INSERT` more rows to fix problems -- this leaves an audit trail of what happened and when.

Comment: +1 But any case the procedure which verifies/recalculates (and reports about an incident if wrong value detected) the balance(s) must exist.